# How to change the default term path "taxonomy/term/[tid]"

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Am using drupal 7 for my project.

Here am facing for custom url change.

My website url is www.example.com/plans/1. Above url need to change as www.example.com/plan-name.

Pls suggest to me to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you try pathauto? https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Answer (score 0):

Please go Configuration->search and metadata -> url aliases -> pattern.

Check over to the Taxonomy Term Path. If you have created the *plan* as Taxonomy.

Go to the Pattern for the Taxonomy *plan* and then create the URL path of the plan

If you want to display the Id in URL,give plan/[term:tid] or taxonomy name give it as plan/[term:name].